# What can I expect from a Minecraft Server running FTB with 3gbs of RAM?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast, minecraft-java-edition-server

My rented (fragnet) server has 3gb's of RAM. I have not the slightest clue what this means for my server. (This is the only information they freely give on the server, I'm in the process of attempting to acquire more information.)

I'm interested in knowing what I can accomplish or allow on the server with this amount of ram. Information I'm interested in includes but isn't necessarily limited to, how many players can play at once before quality of gameplay is hindered, how many estimated chunks could be realistically loaded at one time before gameplay is hindered, what tasks or endeavors use what is considered 'large amounts of ram' and how much ram is considered a 'large amount'?

My server is running Feed The Beast, so please take this into consideration with your calculations and estimates.

Edit: Ok they have replied to my forum post, this is their exact reply;

> All of our machines are equipped with enterprise-grade hardware from reliable brands. In the case of Minecraft server hosting machines, they are all running out of Intel Xeon E3 series of processors with high per-core performance (E3-1240v2 / E3-1270v2) which is optimal for running Minecraft servers. The RAM you pay for is entirely dedicated to your server, our machines are equipped with memory from Corsair, Crucial and Kingston.

Comment: A single stat with no other information doesn't give us enough information in order to be able to help.

Comment: I don't know that you're going to get a satisfactory answer to this, because modded Minecraft is just not a consistent enough beast (heh) to have a well-known performance profile under the huge variety of conditions it can be run under. Unmodded Minecraft servers are enough of a black box when it comes to diagnosing performance issues with "tasks that use large amounts of ram", and modded Minecraft has just so many more unknown lines of code added. It's not a bad question, but it might be a "long tail" question that sits around for a while.

Comment: Please keep discussion to chat and away from the comment section. If anyone has an opinion about the capabilities of said hardware, please mention them below in an answer.

Comment: I will have a tested answer for you by the end of the day. Performance reports and screenshots galore (8ish hours).

Comment: @Oak: Where is the link to chat for this question?

Comment: @mellamokb he means enter the chat room normally and discuss the question there. The chat link is in the upper right corner of the webpage.

Comment: me neither, voting to reopen - the possibility that no canonical answer exists does not make this question unclear, it merely means it could remain un-answered for indefinite time...

Comment: To be honest with you, a server with 3GB of RAM is not that good for FTB. From my experience running FTB on Minecraft hosting services, I would recommend 5GB unless you don't mind dealing with significant lag.

Answer (score 2):

3GB of RAM running heavily modded Minecraft...
According to my personal experience with running servers and playing modded versions of Minecraft, I would say the server could support about 3-4 people at most with medium lag.

Answer (score 0):

I have had experiences with my 5 gigs of ram computer running a server with me and a friend on it and it had a lot of lag. It depends also on how much of the world is loaded (a "loaded" area depends on your render distance. Far: 400 blocks, Normal: 256 blocks, Small: 128 blocks and Tiny: 56 blocks). I would recommend not using a texture pack and have graphics on fast with a small or tiny render distance on all computers that are being used on the server (each player has the same settings).

Comment: Loaded distance in multiplayer is set by the server and is independent of render distance.